# How to list out associated models in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a `:gallery` model that `has_many` `:photos`, with `belongs_to` `:gallery`
How do I list out all the `photos` that has the same `photos.gallery_id` in the `gallery#show`

I'm trying to create a gallery that has many photos and listing all the photos with the same id in the gallery#show using a bxslider.

```
Gallery(
id: integer, 
title: string, 
description_en: text, 
created_at: datetime, 
updated_at: datetime, 
image_file_name: string, 
image_content_type: string, 
image_file_size: integer, 
image_updated_at: datetime, 
user_id: integer, 
description_zh: text, 
tag: string, 
publish: boolean)

Photo(
id: integer, 
caption_en: text, 
caption_zh: text, 
image_file_name: string, 
image_content_type: string, 
image_file_size: integer, 
image_updated_at: datetime, 
gallery_id: integer, 
created_at: datetime, 
updated_at: datetime, 
position: integer, 
publish: boolean)
```

Comment: It didn't work when I tried gallery.photos. In my gallery model, I haven't got an id that reference BACK TO the photos. But I do have id that reference the gallery FROM the photos.

Comment: You would iterate through `gallery.photos` as @DaveNewton already has pointed out - but maybe you should start by reading how associations in rails work http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Have you added the association in the model?

class Gallery
    has_many :photos
end

Comment: Yes it's there. I'm also reading up the guide max suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def show
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
end

#gallery#show
@gallery.photos
```

Note: you should use the @ symbol to reference the instance variable that is set on the controller.